# How to use variables in a curl post?

Tags: php, post, curl, parse-platform

I am creating a php script that will use curl to add a new row in my Parse database. I am having difficulty adding variables to my setopt statement. If anyone could lead me in the right direction, then I would greatly appreciate it.

This is my PHP code that is executing a curl statment:

```
//curl commands to send information to parse
  $ch = curl_init('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/className');

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array('X-Parse-Application-Id:secret1',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key:secret2',
    'Content-Type: application/json'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  "{\"Name\":\"$deviceName\"}" );

echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The response that I get back is:

> {"code":107,"error":"invalid JSON"}

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't encode an array before sending the data?

For Example (untested):

```
$arr = [ "Name" => $deviceName ];
$arr_string = json_encode($arr);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($arr_string)
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arr_string );
```